# Array elements Comparison Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

As a beginner I am doing online problems to understand arrays, this is not homework but practice. Any advice helps!

**The code should take user input**.

**Problem:**

Print two space-separated integers denoting the respective comparison scores earned by A and B.

- Sample Input

5 6 7
3 6 10

- Sample Output

1 1

**Explanation**

In this example:
A = (a0, a1, a2) where the values are (5,6,7)

B = (b0,b1,b2) where the values are (3,6,10)

Compare each individual score:

a0 > b0 ==> so A receives 1 point.

a0 = b0 ==> nobody receives a point.

b0 > a0 ==> so B receives 1 point.

A's comparison score is 1 and B's comparison score is 1. Thus, we print 1 1 on a single line.

**Approach 1:**

First I though of implementing this as a 2d array but I only got this far as I am not sure where to implement the comparison:

```
public class CompareElem2DArray{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array2d [][]= new int[3][3];
        System.out.println("Please enter 3 marks for A and 3 marks for B: ");

        for(int a = 0; a<3; a++) //row
        {
            for(int b=0; b<3; b++)//column
            {
                int array2d[a][b] = in.nextInt();
            }

        }

        for (int column = 0; column<3; column++)
        {
            for(int row=0; row<3; row++)
            {
                System.out.println( array2d[column][row]+" ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

This is my second attempt without using 2D arrays.

```
public class Comparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a0 = in.nextInt();
        int a1 = in.nextInt();
        int a2 = in.nextInt();
        int b0 = in.nextInt();
        int b1 = in.nextInt();
        int b2 = in.nextInt();

        int a[] = new int[3];
        int b[] = new int[3];
        int firstAns = 0;
        int secondAns = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            int a[i] = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
            int b[j] = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(b[j]);
        }
        for(int z = 0; z<3; z++)
            {
                if(a[z]>b[z])
                    {
                    firstAns++;
                }
            else if(a[z]<b[z])
                {
                secondAns++;
            }
            else
                {
                return;
            }
        }
     System.out.println(firstAns);
      System.out.println(secondAns);           
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to get for answers, but my first thought is to suggest that you think hard about your coding style.  Being consistent about brace placement, naming, spacing, etc. matters a lot.  Your code needs to be read by you and others.  That might be more important than the execution.  Your code is hard to read.  Java standard suggests putting braces at the end of lines rather than on the next line.  C# developers tend to put them on the next line.  I prefer the former.  You should, too.

Comment: A 2D array doesn't make much sense here because you have only two arrays, and making an `int[2][x]` array is needlessly complicated.

Comment: There is no question in your "question."  You'll catch more fish if you say something like, "here's my code, and here's the error message that I get when I try to compile it, what did I do wrong?"  or  "Here's my code, here's what I get when I run it, Here's what I thought I would get, what am I missing?"

Comment: @duffymo - thank you for the advice, I will apply it in the future.

Comment: You won't get as much help if all you say is, "here's my problem, tell me how to solve it."  But, here's a general "how-to-solve-it tip:"  Think about what _you_ would do if you had to solve the same problem with pencil and paper instead of using a computer.  Whatever the steps are that you would do,... think about how you could tell the computer to perform those same steps.

Comment: @Zircon - true, it did seem a bit complicated, I though that was because I was not sure about the implementation.

Comment: @james large - thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing

```
    int[] ar = {5,6,7,3,6,10};
    int halflen= (ar.length)/2;
    int[] result = new int[halflen];

    for(int i=0,j=halflen;i<halflen;i++,j++)
    {
        result[i]=ar[i]-ar[j];
    }
```

Now you have a array with 3 results , if 0 is draw whatever how is > 0 made the point you can eliminate the array inside loop if you want and add your if ther too like :

```
         If (ar [i] > ar [j]) A++;
         If (ar [i]<ar [j]) B++;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In approach 1., I think that what you need is [3][2] or [2][3] array (you have 2 sets of data, in one set there are 3 numbers).
Then the comparison goes in second loop (in this case, array2d is [3][2]):

```
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      //comparison goes here
    }
```

You need to compare values of array2d[i][0] with array2d[i][1].

When input is: 5 6 7 3 6 10

Your 2d array is something like:

5 6 7

3 6 10

So the second loop is comparing 5 with 3, 6 with 6 and 7 with 10.